# In graphql-codegen Is There Any Way to Make Generated Types Derive From a Common Type?

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I am generating Typescript types from a GraphQL API using the `graphql-codegen` package.  It works great ... except that it makes types like these:

```
export type PolicyTypeConnection = {
  __typename?: 'PolicyTypeConnection';
  count?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']['output']>;
  edges: Array<Maybe<PolicyTypeEdge>>;
};

export type PolicyRuleTypeConnection = {
  __typename?: 'PolicyRuleTypeConnection';
  count?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']['output']>;
  edges: Array<Maybe<PolicyRuleTypeEdge>>;
};

... imagine a ton more that follow the same pattern
```

It would be handy if I could refer to all those types as a group.  In other words, I'd like to have a type:

```
export type TypeConnection = {
  count?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']['output']>;
  edges: Array<Maybe<any>>;
};
```

and then have `PolicyTypeConnection` and every other `*TypeConnection` type extend that type.

Is there any way to get `graphql-codegen` to do something like this (perhaps using the `scalar` config option somehow?), or is the only solution to modify the generated types?